# replace last two octets of an ip with * PHP

Tags: php

I want to be able to replace the numbers between the last two octets with *'s

`127.0.0.1` becomes `127.0.*.*`
`88.88.88.88` becomes `88.88.**.**`

How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i have messed about with regex but cant seem to get it right, I can use long2ip to replace them with digits but that isnt what im looking for.

Comment: I think what they were alluding to is to show what you've tried and what it produces. People like to see an effort being made before helping someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `explode` to split a string by a delimiter:

```
$myIP = "127.0.0.1";
$ipOctets = explode('.', $myIP);
$newIp = $ipOctets[0] . '.' . $ipOctets[1] . '.' . preg_replace('/./', '*', $ipOctets[4]) . '.' . preg_replace('/./', '*', $ipOctets[3]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `$octets[0] . '.' . $octets[1] . '.' . preg_replace('/./', '*', $octets[2]) . '.' . preg_replace('/./', '*', $octets[3]);`

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, try dissecting and rebuilding the IP address as four separate items.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo substr($ip, 0, strrpos($ip, '.')).'.***';
```

Comment: Technically, your answer does not accurately answer the OPs query, as it masks only the _last_ octet, but happily, that's just what I was looking for. 